# Visual Studio Code, workspace is re-adding removed mercurial repository on load

Tags: visual-studio-code, mercurial

I used the terminal of my VSCode to cd into the folder of a different project and execute a mercurial command.

This added that folder to the source control view of my workspace in VSCode.
When I tell VSCode to remove the folder it does so. But every time I open the workspace, Source Control has re-added the folder and VSCode slows down because that folder contains 1.8k+ uncommitted changes.

How do you make VSCode source control permanently forget a managed folder?

Comment: As far as it goes, source control isn't "re-adding" the folder - you added it once and it has recorded that.  That seems separate from why VSCode won't let you permanently "forget" it.

Comment: Semantically correct. In which case I will change my question. If the function "close repository" doesn't actually do what it's name implies, but instead only hides it. Where do I find the actual "remove repository from workspace" function in VSCode.